# telephone number detection in samsung mobile email client

Tags: android, mobile, samsung-mobile, email-client, mailer

I'm sending mailer across my team and testing but it is working fine the other devices and clients except Samsung Galaxy Email client. the number is totally hidden. I don't know whats the problem is but it's not working at all. I have also used the Meta Tag format detection but doesn't work.

```
<meta name="format-detection" content="telephone=no">
```

help!